# how to send data from telegram bot inline keyboard to specific column in google spreadsheet?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, bots, telegram

I am not really familiar with the Telegram API and need to use JSON.

I want to create an inline keyboard that have options [yes/no] only.

Then, send it to a spreadsheet.

I managed to create the inline keyboard but nothing happens when I press it.

Is it possible to send data to a spreadsheet from the Telegram bot?

Code:

`{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"yes","callback_data":"yes"}]]}`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimial, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and any errors or logs you might get to assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible :)

You'd first need to setup a webhook for your telegram bot -

```
var telegramToken = 'Your-Telegram-Bot-Token-Goes-Here';

function setup() {
  var method = 'setWebhook';
  var payload = {
    url: ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
  }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + telegramToken + '/' + method, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

and then setup a simple `doPost(e)` to capture incoming data from said webhook. You can refer some of the code from a bot that's i'd built [here](https://script.gs/build-a-telegram-bot-using-apps-script/) but please feel free to share more details with what you require so I could assist accordingly.